# How to change between excel sheets?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have more excel files in a dir from that I want to extract data (from different cells). How can I apply for loop to get datas from the first file's first sheet and after that move to second sheet and get datas from the second sheet.

```
for file in glob.glob('N:\mydata\*.xls'):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info=True, encoding_override="utf-8")
    sheets = book.sheet_names()

    for index, sh in enumerate(sheets):
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(index)
        rows, cols = sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols
        print "Number of rows: %s   Number of cols: %s" % (rows, cols)

        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                thecell = sheet.cell(row, col)
                ertek = thecell.value
                xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
                xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
                bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
                pattern_colour = book.colour_map[bgx]

                # mydata
                if row == 7 and col == 9:
                    mydata= ertek
                    print mydata
```

Comment: Your code seems to do exactly that. What do you want to do with these data?

Comment: But from the second sheet I would need different data (different cell position). And I dont know where to define it.

Comment: You can use a dictionary (or even a list of tuples) like `pos = {0: (7, 9), 1: (5, 13), 2: (8, 4)}` to store positions (row and column) by sheet number, and then use it like this: `if row == pos[index][0] and col == pos[index][1]:`, where `index` is your sheet number.